# Deploy to Engine Yard failing: 'key not found: :ciphers'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, engineyard

I can't deploy using the ey command:

```
$ ey deploy -e myapp
Loading application data from Engine Yard Cloud...
key not found: :ciphers
```

```
engineyard version 3.2.5
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

I think this has something to do with ssl. Ruby 2.5.3 was installed with `rbenv` and is using openssl 1.1.1 (I think I remember seeing that) though not sure how to find this after actual install...

Comment: What is your version of `rest-client`?

Comment: @romnoks     rest-client (1.8.0)

Comment: Try installing version 1.6 or 2.0.1

Comment: @romnoks  None compatible:  engineyard was resolved to 3.2.5, which depends on      engineyard-cloud-client (~> 2.1) was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on        rest-client (~> 1.7)

Comment: Ok, this is predictable behavior. Try to run `bundle update`. You need to fix gem version compatibility.

Comment: @romnoks I don't think this is resolvable, I put `gem 'rest-client', '2.0.1'` in my gem file and did `bundle update rest-client`. That was the error. I won't allow above `1.x` or below `1.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should note that the EngineYard gem hasn't been getting updates and is deprecated due to it successor ey-core. It's recommended people use ey-core. It should resolve the issue and allow you to deploy.

Comment: Thanks Callum, and thanks for the support online today. Just for posterity, to be clear, the solution is: don't use the `engineyard` gem, but use `ey-core` gem. And also the cli program will be `ey-core` (not `engineyard`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Callum. Just for posterity, to be clear, the solution is: don't use the engineyard gem, but use ey-core gem. And also the cli program will be ey-core (not engineyard)